# Somekind of "black sparkles" flying through screen Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, intel

Somekind of "black sparkles" flying through screen Ubuntu 16.04 when Im using external screen on a lenovo X220 laptop. (Intel HD Graphics 3000)
They do not appear in laptops own screen.
I have tried several monitors. Anybody who has the same and knows the fix for this, or suggestions what to try?

PROBLEM SOLVED, MY VGA CABLE WAS BROKEN...
Bought a new one and works like a charm.

Comment: can you take screenshot of those black sparkles?

Comment: I have tried but they do not appear on image, they are very tiny. Also when I open up a new window of some program, that is not on full screen it makes odd black line of those sparkles to the end of the screen. They do not appear at all if I don't have any software window opened on the screen.

Comment: Do the black sparkles also show on the screen when running a live session from a live Ubuntu DVD/USB? If so you have a hardware problem, possibly due to overheating inside the laptop. Overheating could be caused by a number of different things including dust build-up inside the laptop.